# Passing parameters between states in Ember.StateManager

Tags: ember.js

When using Ember.StateManager, the most common transition between Em.States involve some parameter or another. Currently, I am using instance variables within the StateManager to pass parameters between States, when I do go from one state to another using goToState. This seems incredibly ugly to me. Is there a reason there is not a more standard way of passing parameters? Or should I use a different pattern.

For example,

```
App.stateManager = Em.StateManager.create({
  initialState: 'listContacts',
  listContacts: Em.ViewState.create({
    ...
    actionSelectContact: function(manager, context) {
      manager.set('selectedContact', context);
      manager.goToState('showContact');
    }
  }),
  showContact: Em.ViewState.create({
    enter: function(manager, transition) {
      var contactToShow = manager.get('selectedContact');
      ...
    }
    ...
  })
})
```

Is there a better way to do this parameter passing between states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom Dale just added a transitionTo method to deal with this. transitionTo takes a context object along with the name of the target state. Now within your action you could do something like,

```
viewStates = Ember.StateManager.create({
  showingPeople: Ember.ViewState.create({
    view: ContactListView
  }),

  showDetailAction: function(mgr, selectedPerson) {
    mgr.transitionTo('showingPersonDetail', selectedPerson);
  },

  showingPersonDetail: Ember.ViewState.create({
    setupContext: function(manager, context) {
      this.set('person', context);
    },
    view: PersonDetailView
  })
})
```

You could also get more fancier and pass parameters for multiple states along the way like,

```
stateManager.transitionTo(['planters', { company: true }], ['nuts', { product: true }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Ember expert, but I think you could achieve this using `stateManager.send()` method where the second argument will be the object you want to pass between states.

Most of your answer is in the [Ember.StateManager documentation](http://ember-docs.herokuapp.com/#doc=Ember.StateManager&src=false).

There was a pull request in Ember talking about extra params in `goToState()` method [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/385), but it has been closed because `goToState()` should only be used internally [as joewest says here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/415#issuecomment-3600461) with tomdale:

> goToState should only be called from within a state. To accomplish this, just implement an action that takes additional parameters, and have it call goToState for you.

Comment: Although goToState is internal to the state manager, it is in effect a transition to a completely different state. The current state has no implicit knowledge of the target state, except perhaps the name. Are you suggesting that the transition be effected by an action in a common parent state? If so, how would one prepare the target state with the context passed down? Do we create an instance of the state, with context setup already, passed to goToState, instead of the state name? This gets messier transitioning from a leaf node of one branch to a leaf node of a completely different branch.